# asp.net : exclude control in updatepanel from doing async postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have placed a user control inside update panel after doing asynchronous postback of page associated js file of that user control is not working so that is there any method to exclude a control from updatepanel in another word i don't want to post that user control.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlAnswerList" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
                       // another code that required to placed inside updatepanel

                         <div id="miancontainer" class="containerr"           
                            <klmsuc:Share ID="shareUserControl" runat="server" />

                       // another code that required to placed inside updatepanel



                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set UpdateMode=Conditional and provide exclusive Triggers for the UpdatePanel.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Use a PostBackTrigger to perform exclusion rather than having to specify a large number of includes.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkExport" runat="server" OnClick="lnkExport_Click" Text="Export Data"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkExport" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add some controls in code behind and in the right event and register it for exclusion(postback) instead and AsyncPostBack which is a ajax call.

**ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnAdd);**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036830/184572

```
protected void grdExpense_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btnAdd = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("btnAdd");
        if (btnAdd != null)
        {
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnAdd);
        }

    }
```

look for another similar page which excludes all the controls in a gridview

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Assign-PostBack-Trigger-Full-PostBack-for-LinkButton-inside-GridView-within-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet.aspx

```
private void RegisterPostBackControl()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        LinkButton lnkFull = row.FindControl("lnkFull") as LinkButton;
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(lnkFull);
    }
}
```