# A control with ID 'imgbtn_excel_gridout' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel3'

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I am using this code but this is not working..**

***1. When I remove update panel from this code It will working but with update panel this code not working.*
 *2. I also use trigger for button to send asynchronous request .***

```
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
             CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" AllowPaging="True" 
             onpageindexchanging="GridView2_PageIndexChanging" 
             onrowdatabound="GridView2_RowDataBound" 
             onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" 
             DataKeyNames="id,date" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                       BorderWidth="3px" CellSpacing="2" PageSize="5" GridLines="None">
             <Columns>
                <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="DATE" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}">
                --%>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="REF. ID">
                 <ItemStyle BackColor="#33CC33" BorderColor="Maroon" Font-Bold="True" 
                     Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#CC3300" />
                 </asp:BoundField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="AUTHO. NAME" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemType" HeaderText="ITEM TYPE">
                 <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                 </asp:BoundField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="QUANTITY">
                 <HeaderStyle Width="130px" />
                 </asp:BoundField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="BRAND" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="SubType" HeaderText="SUB TYPE">
                 <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                 </asp:BoundField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="DATE"  
                     DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}">

                 <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                 </asp:BoundField>
                     <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="QuantityInPiece" HeaderText="Quantity In Piece" >
                     <ItemTemplate > <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuantityInPiece") %>'></asp:Label> </ItemTemplate>
                       <FooterTemplate> 
                             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_excel_gridout" runat="server" 
                                 ImageUrl="~/images/excel.jpg" Width="20px" Height="15px" 
                                 onclick="imgbtn_excel_gridout_Click">
                         </asp:ImageButton>
                         </FooterTemplate> 
                     </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
             <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" />
             <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
             <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
             <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
             <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
             <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
             <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
             <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />

             <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>

             <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

             <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>

             <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
         </asp:GridView>

                       <br />
       </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgbtn_excel_gridout" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the approach being done here:

[ASP.NET - Adding an UpdatePanel trigger to a LinkButton inside a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276544/asp-net-adding-an-updatepanel-trigger-to-a-linkbutton-inside-a-gridview)

Use your ImageButton control instead of LinkButton.