# How to assign UpdatePanel Trigger's control ID with button's from gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, triggers, updatepanel

currently I have a UpdatePanel for jQuery Dialog use, which contains a GridView.

And that GridView contains a FileUpload control in footer and EmptyDataTemplate

In order to get FileUpload control work in javascript, I know that we need trigger.

However, the button that I wanna assign as trigger is inside GridView's template...

when the button btnAdd clicked, file in FileUpload control will be saved.

---

Here is the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlEditExpense" runat="server">
      <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd"/>
      </Triggers>
            ......................
                 ........................
                       .........................
      <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdExpense" ShowHeader="True" ShowFooter="True"
           AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           <Columns>
                 ...................
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                       <FooterTemplate>
                              <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                       </FooterTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If I put the button id directly in trigger's control ID like this, error come up saying btnAdd could not be found...

what should I do to get FileUpload control work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works

```
protected void grdExpense_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btnAdd = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("btnAdd");
        if (btnAdd != null)
        {
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnAdd);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try registering the post back control from code behind like this:

```
protected void grdExpense_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btnAdd = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("btnAdd");
        if (btnAdd != null)
        {
            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btnAdd);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried, but it still doesn't work. Do I need to add any other code beside this?

Comment: Did you link this event to `OnRowCreated` of the gridview?Step through the code and make sure that it goes into the `if` block.If it still doesn't work try @erich007's approach

Comment: yes I did, but still doesn't work. do I have to change UpdateMode to conditional?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding a trigger to upnlEditExpense maybe you can try to add an update panel around the link button inside the template with no triggers...

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlBtnAdd" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work even if I add ContentTemplate base on your solution.

Comment: OK, last suggestion :) Make btnAdd ClientIDMode=static on your very first version

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this post helped me, but I found that registering the control in the scriptmanager works only if the updatepanels UpdateMode is set to "Always". If its set to "Conditional" this approach does not work.

I found another approach that always works which is to add triggers to the updatepanel in the DataBound() event of the gridview:

```
    Dim CheckBoxTrigger As UpdatePanelControlTrigger = New AsyncPostBackTrigger()
    Dim SelectCheckBox As CheckBox
    For i = 0 To GridViewEquipment.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
        SelectCheckBox = GridViewEquipment.Rows(i).Cells(12).FindControl("CheckBoxSign")
        CheckBoxTrigger.ControlID = SelectCheckBox.UniqueID
        UpdatePanelEquipment.Triggers.Add(CheckBoxTrigger)
    Next
```